# SSH allowing remote hosts to connect to local forwarded ports

Tags: ssh, redhat, port-forwarding, selinux, rhel7

I'm currently facing an issue with a RHEL 7.0 regarding the ssh option -g (i.e remote hosts connection to local forwarded ports ).

I'm establishing a connection with port forwarding, from a server on  myserver_ip address , with the usual command line :

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@server_fqn -L9090:other_server_ip:9080 -g
```

When I point my browser (or try to fetch something with curl I get a connection refused exception ) :

```
curl -X GET "http://myserver_ip:9090"
curl: (7) Failed to connect to myserver_ip port 9090: No route to host
```

If I do the same on a Ubuntu server it works perfectly, however on RHEL it simply does not work.

I suspected the firewall, selinux, even network connectivity.

In order to solve/troubleshoot this I've tried the following :

- disabled the firewall (`service firewalld stop`)
- checked that selinux manages the 9090 as valid http port (`semanage port -l  | grep 9090`), it was ok
- checked that the port is open via netstat ( `netstat -alptn  | grep 9090`
   ) , seems ok , I've got an ssh process listening on 9090
- checked that the server recieves the packets on port 9090 of the ehternet interface ( `tcpdump -i ens192 'port 9090' -v` ) , and indeed packets are recieved ...

So basically it conformed that the system receives the requests on the interface, an ssh process is listening on all interfaces on the given port, however the ssh process does not forward packets to the other side ...

I'm really out of leads for troubleshooting, so If you have any suggestions, please do not hesitate, I'd really appreciate some help.

Thanks,

Comment: I believe you should check `GatewayPorts` and `PermitOpen` option in `sshd_config(5)` manual page. I don't want to blame you what exactly is wrong, but these options are related to the ports you are able/unable to bind with port-forwarding.

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately setting neither the GatewayPorts (host:port) nor the PermitOpen (set to yes) does not seem to fix the situation. Even both set, the situation is the same ...

Comment: Try using localhost:9090.

Comment: Hi, localhost:9090 will bind the forwarder port on the loopback, it will not allow external access from a remote server. More interesting, sshd doc says GatewayPorts defaults to all hosts all ports, so I think this parameter is irrelevant in the present situation.

Comment: The one check that I was expecting first, was: ```
nc myserver_ip 9090
or
telnet myserver_ip 9090
``` also, do a: ```
nmap myserver_ip -p 9090
```

Comment: That works. I can access the port from the server on which I'm running the ssh client. I can run a telnet on port 9090 and the curl command using localhost from the server I'm running ssh client.

Answer (score 1):

Curl has already told you the answer. It's not about SSH, its not about firewalls, it's not about selinux.

```
no route to host
```

The machine where you are running curl does not know where it should send packets intended for (the ip address it associates with) my server_ip

Comment: The curl command executed locally, via the localhost address, on the server that runs the ssh forwarding,  works perfectly. If it was a name resolution or network configuration issue on the other end , I would have the same error locally which is not the case. Basically on RHEL it simply does not work on any other interface then locahost. It works perfectly on a Ubuntu server that has the same network configuration. Any ideas ?